# iOS code is loading the wrong nib file?

Tags: ios, tableview, nib

I have an app that is a list. When you tap on a list item, it loads a separate nib specifically for that cell. This second nib has two buttons, each associated with yet another nib file. The first implementation of this code in my Cell1.m file works fine to open the nib on response to the button pressed inside the detail views with no errors / warmings:

```
-(IBAction)wikibuttonPressed:(id)sender {
WebView1 *detailvc = [[WebView1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebView1" bundle:nil];
[detailvc setTitle:@"Wikipedia"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailvc animated:YES];
[detailvc release];

}

-(IBAction)biobuttonPressed:(id)sender {
WebView2 *detailvc2 = [[WebView2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebView2" bundle:nil];
[detailvc2 setTitle:@"The White House"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailvc2 animated:YES];
[detailvc2 release];
}
```

However, when I try to implement this code on Cell2.m, rather than loading this:

```
-(IBAction)biobuttonPressed:(id)sender {
WebView4 *detailvc4 = [[WebView4 alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebView4" bundle:nil];
[detailvc4 setTitle:@"The White House"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailvc4 animated:YES];
[detailvc4 release];
}


-(IBAction)wikibuttonPressed:(id)sender {
WebView3 *detailvc3 = [[WebView3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebView3" bundle:nil];
[detailvc3 setTitle:@"Wikipedia"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailvc3 animated:YES];
[detailvc3 release];

}
```

it loads the nib files associated in my first snippet of code (WebView1 & WebView2, rather than WebView3 and WebView4). Additionally, I get an warning on Cell2.m saying bioButtonPressed and wikiButtonPressed were not defined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, I checked that the .h files are correct, as well as the .xib outlets being set.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the definition of those methods matches in Cell2.h, and that the outlets are correctly set.